# SEO and page with checkbox before accessing site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, seo

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project in which people who visit the site MUST check a checkbox in order to access the whole site (after checking it a cookie is set to to not show the first page again).

I made it working but my interrogation is about SEO: how google, bing or any robots can reference my website if they are not allowed to go through the page with the checkbox ? Is there a way in Rails to skip this first for some robots ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You could use JS to launch a floating div over the top of the page which hassles people to check the checkbox.  Robots won't see this as they don't run the javascript, they just access the dom, which is all there in the background anyway.  This is the standard approach.  BTW when i say "floating" i mean with `position:fixed;` so they can't scroll away from it.

Comment: Yes that was one of my thought but if user disable javascript he would be able to access everything even if the checkbox is not validated. That's why I decided to not use js and buid it with rails.

Comment: Its an interesting request: the user MUST do something to see your information on YOUR site but should be able to see the same site WITHOUT checking anything in the Google page cache? Well: you can check the agent in the request.user_agent. But this can be faked.

Comment: I finally moved to the js.cookie solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: Most bigger search engines render pages with JavaScript altogether. http://www.googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html Cookies again, sometimes are used to better understand content (rarely, but they're still used)